# basic use of java mime-util

Tags: java

I was hoping someone could clarify some facts about [mime-util](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mime-util/)?
Firstly:  my biggest issue is that I am not sure what to import to actually use the library (small java statement but very vital). :):)

Second I think that mime-util can work out the type of a file from a byte[] array and/or stream is that correct?  If so what method should be called?

Lastly, would someone be able to give a quick example on how to get the mime type?  (not as important as I have pieced together snippets from other questions but I have know guaranty that it will work).

Comment: Maybe this gives you some options - http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source may help but this lib is old and now unsupported.

You may take a look at the [Java Source Test](http://mime-util.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mime-util/trunk/eu.medsea.mimeutil.test/src/eu/medsea/mimeutil/test/MimeUtilTest.java?revision=123&view=markup).